# Using Cloudinary React Component with Bootrap React for Images

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, cloudinary

I am showing images in Bootstrap Cards as React components as below:

```
         <Card
            style={{ width: "18rem" }}
            key={index}
            className="box"
            border="danger"
          >
            <Card.Header>
              {card.brand} - {card.series}
            </Card.Header>
            <Card.Img
              variant="top"
              src={card.image}    
              fluid
            />
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>
                {card.player} (#
                {card.card_number.$numberDouble}) {card.variation}
              </Card.Title>
            </Card.Body>
            <ListGroup className="list-group-flush">
              <ListGroupItem>
                Print Run - {card.print_run.$numberDouble}
              </ListGroupItem>
              <ListGroupItem>Career Stage - {card.career_stage} </ListGroupItem>
              <ListGroupItem>For Trade - {card.forTrade}</ListGroupItem>
            </ListGroup>
            <Card.Footer className="text-muted ">{card.team}</Card.Footer>
          </Card>
```

Independently of this I can render Cloudinary images via its React component such as:

```
<CloudinaryContext cloudName="dkwmxhsem">
          <Image publicId="Was-Ter-266front_w0lcdz">
            <Transformation width="200" crop="scale" angle="10" />
          </Image>
</CloudinaryContext>
```

but is is possible to render the transformed cloudfoundry image as the `img src` value in `<Card.Img />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to generate the Cloudinary URL without it being in an image tag, you have to use Cloudinary core Javascript functionality that the React SDK is built on top of. To do that, you can do the following:

```
import {Cloudinary} from 'cloudinary-core';
const cloudinaryCore = new cloudinary.Cloudinary({cloud_name: 'demo'});
const SampleImg = () => (
    <img src={cloudinaryCore.url('sample')} />
);
```

More info [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/react_integration#using_core_cloudinary_javascript_features) on Cloudinary's website.